# How to retrieve details of the first model in Backbone.js by default?

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to display the details of the first model in Backbone by default, How can I go about this?

```
          this.wineList = new WineCollection(); 
          this.wineList.fetch();
```

After retrieving the value i would like to display the first model. To retrieve model details given its id, my code looks like this -

```
              this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
          this.wineView = new WineView({model: this.wine});
          this.wineView.render();
```

Any direction in this regard will be very helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: You know that fetch() is done asynchronously in the background, so wineList.get will not have data yet in the following row, right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, helps me deal with another issue i am encountering.I will edit my question accordingly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, what you are looking for is the at method http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-at

```
this.wine = this.wineList.at(0);
```

Comment: Since collections inherit most of the underscore methods, you can also do `this.wineList.first()` if you like that kind of sugar.

Comment: @verdure: And your variable is named `id`, which is confusing if you really want positional access. Should be named `idx` or something like that.